# spring integration rabbit-mq json MessagingException

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration to send notifications and as an error test case, I am sending in malformed JSON (a Map) and am getting MessagingException which seems to just go on and on.. not stopping.. I have to kill the Application.

So want to know how to capture this, may be via errorChannel. Code examples would be helpful.

My Spring Integration config:

```
 <!-- channel to connect to disruption exchange -->
    <int-amqp:publish-subscribe-channel id="inputChannel"
                                        connection-factory="connectionFactory"
                                        exchange="notification.exchange"/>

    <int:json-to-object-transformer input-channel="inputChannel"
                                    output-channel="notificationChannel"
                                    type="java.util.Map"/>

    <int:channel id="notificationChannel">
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="loggingChannel"/>
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>

    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="loggingChannel" log-full-message="true" logger-name="tapInbound" level="INFO"/>

    <!-- depending on the deviceType route to either apnsChannel or gcmChannel -->
    <int:router ref="notificationTypeRouter" input-channel="notificationChannel"/>

    <!-- apple push notification channel-->
    <int:channel id="apnsChannel"/>

    <!-- service activator to process disruptionNotificationChannel -->
    <int:service-activator input-channel="apnsChannel" ref="apnsPushNotificationService" method="pushNotification"/>

    <!-- google cloud messaging notification channel-->
    <int:channel id="gcmChannel"/>

    <!-- service activator to process disruptionNotificationChannel -->
    <int:service-activator input-channel="gcmChannel" ref="gcmPushNotificationService" method="pushNotification"/>

    <!-- error channel to may be log to file or email or store to db in the future -->
    <int:channel id="errorChannel"/>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel" ref="notificationErrorHandler" method="handleFailedNotification"/>

    <!-- Infrastructure -->
    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
                               host="${spring.rabbitmq.host}"
                               port="${spring.rabbitmq.port}"
                               username="${spring.rabbitmq.username}"
                               password="${spring.rabbitmq.password}"/>

    <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>

    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>

    <rabbit:fanout-exchange name="notification.exchange"/>
```

I also have an error handler:

```
public class NotificationErrorHandler {

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotificationErrorHandler.class);

    public void handleFailedNotification(Message<MessageHandlingException> message) {
        Map<String, Object> map = (Map) message.getPayload();
        Notification notification = Notification.fromMap(map);
        saveToBD(notification);
    }

    private void saveToBD(Notification notification) {
        LOG.error("[Notification-Error-Handler] Couldn't Send Push notification: device='{}', type='{}', pushId='{}', message='{}', uid='{}'",
                new Object[]{notification.getDevice(),
                        notification.getDeviceType(),
                        notification.getDeviceToken(),
                        notification.getBody(),
                        notification.getUid()});
    }
}
```

This is the exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failure occured in AMQP listener while attempting to convert and dispatch Message.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: failed to transform message; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: [B@7a707c2c; line: 7, column: 2]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.channel.AbstractSubscribableAmqpChannel$DispatchingMessageListener.onMessage(AbstractSubscribableAmqpChannel.java:202)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:799)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: failed to transform message; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: [B@7a707c2c; line: 7, column: 2]
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:44)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:68)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:160)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.channel.AbstractSubscribableAmqpChannel$DispatchingMessageListener.onMessage(AbstractSubscribableAmqpChannel.java:181)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: [B@7a707c2c; line: 7, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1419)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:508)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:437)
```

Hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance
GM

---

Changes made as per @Gary's answer and its working now:

```
<!-- Infrastructure -->
    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
                               host="${spring.rabbitmq.host}"
                               port="${spring.rabbitmq.port}"
                               username="${spring.rabbitmq.username}"
                               password="${spring.rabbitmq.password}"/>

    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>

    <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>

    <rabbit:direct-exchange name="notification.direct">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="notification.queue" key="notification.queue"/>
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:direct-exchange>

    <rabbit:queue id="notification.queue" name="notification.queue"/>

    <int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="inputChannel"
                                      queue-names="notification.queue"
                                      connection-factory="connectionFactory"
                                      error-channel="errorChannel"/>

    <int:json-to-object-transformer input-channel="inputChannel"
                                    output-channel="notificationChannel"
                                    type="java.util.Map"/>

    <int:channel id="notificationChannel">
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="loggingChannel"/>
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>

    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="loggingChannel" log-full-message="true" logger-name="tapInbound" level="INFO"/>

    <!-- depending on the deviceType route to either apnsChannel or gcmChannel -->
    <int:router ref="notificationTypeRouter" input-channel="notificationChannel"/>

    <!-- apple push notification channel-->
    <int:channel id="apnsChannel"/>

    <!-- service activator to process disruptionNotificationChannel -->
    <int:service-activator input-channel="apnsChannel" ref="apnsPushNotificationService" method="pushNotification"/>

    <!-- google cloud messaging notification channel-->
    <int:channel id="gcmChannel"/>

    <!-- service activator to process disruptionNotificationChannel -->
    <int:service-activator input-channel="gcmChannel" ref="gcmPushNotificationService" method="pushNotification"/>

    <!-- no op channel where message is logged for unknown devices -->
    <int:channel id="noOpChannel"/>

    <!-- service activator to process disruptionNotificationChannel -->
    <int:service-activator input-channel="noOpChannel" ref="noOpPushNotificationService" method="pushNotification"/>

    <!-- error channel to may be log to file or email or store to db in the future -->
    <int:channel id="errorChannel"/>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel" ref="notificationErrorHandler"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you starting the flow with a pub-sub channel? It's not normal to use a pub/sub channel for message distribution.

If you can use a message-driven channel adapter instead, you can add an error-channel.

You can't add an error channel to a pub-sub channel. You can, however inject an error-handler (implements `org.springframework.util.ErrorHandler`) and throw an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` when you detect a fatal error.

You can also use a Json MessageConverter in the channel instead of using a Json transformer downstream in the flow; in that case, the default error handler will detect a message conversion exception and reject the message rather than requeueing it.

Comment: as per your suggestion I have changed "inbound-channel-adapter" and throwing "AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException" in the ErrorHandler. However, I tried using the JsonMessageConverter but was getting errors, so I stuck with json-to-object-transformer as its working.